# Shopify app login issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have switched from legacy to oauth2 authentication on a Shopify app. Now, whenever I visit the app from a stores admin page (My Apps -> App) it redirects me always to the login page instead of logging the store into the app directly (as it did before).

Below is the code there in the finalize method.

```
if response = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  sess = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(params['shop'], response['credentials']['token'])
  ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(sess)
  session[:shopify] = sess
  flash[:notice] = "Logged in"
  redirect_to return_address
  session[:return_to] = nil
else
  flash[:error] = "Could not log in to Shopify store."
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
end
```

When user visits the app from store admin page it does not have request.env['omniauth.auth'] in the request and gets redirected to login page where as it was not the case when we had legacy authentication mechanism.

App url is www.orderlyprint-staging.herokuapp.com.  You can install the app in the test store and try to login into the app from the test store's admin page.

Comment: {"shop"=>"kohler-oberbrunner-and-reichert9767.myshopify.com", "signature"=>"something", "timestamp"=>"1346305711", "controller"=>"login", "action"=>"finalize"} this is what i get in params when ivisit the app from the store

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Shopify Apps originally built using the Shopify App gem and when switching from the Legacy to the oAuth2 authentication solution, you will need to point the Shopify Admin link to the authenticate action instead of the finalize action. So you need to:

Go to the Shopify Partner Admin

Press Edit App Details

Update the "Application URL" to point at the authenticate action instead. For example: 
www.orderlyprint-staging.herokuapp.com/login/authenticate

This will then extract the shop param sent over by Shopify, and do the initial step of the oAuth authentication, and then redirect to the finalize action for completion. This will then login the user automatically without the need for them to input their store URL manually.